# Lists in files into printing the cheapest price. Python

Tags: python

i currently have -

```
showFile = open("products.txt", 'r')
        lines = showFile.readline()
        while lines:
            print(lines)
            lines = showFile.readline()
        showFile.close()
        showFile = open("products.txt", 'r')
        numbers = []
        for line in showFile:
            tokens = line.split(',')
            numbers.append(min(t for t in tokens[0]))
        minValue = min(numbers)
        print(minValue)
```

Products.txt -

```
'Snicker's, 33, 84
'Mars', 18.5, 72
'Bounty', 22, 96
```

so which the 33 is the price, and 84 is the quantity.
and 18.5 is the price and 72 is the quantity and so on.

im trying to make it so it prints something like-
Snickers is $0.39 per unit.
Mars is $0.29 per unit.
Bounty is $0.23 per unit.
Bounty is the most cheapest

Help is Appreciated :D

Comment: Start by dividing one number by the other, then learn about string formatting syntax: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: you shouldn't need to (or want to) open the same file twice just to (1) print to the screen and then to (2) append to a list.  Use the same iterator (in fact, use the `with` context) and accomplish both tasks at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `print repr(tokens)` to show you what's in the `tokens` variable. I suggest you add that and see what it says.

Note that Python has different types of values.  E.g. `"18.5"` or `'18.5'` are strings - these are appropriate for things that are actually strings (e.g. `'Bounty'`) but they're not good for numbers because you can't do maths on them.

If you have a number, you will want to convert it to `float` form (e.g. `18.5`) or `int` form (e.g. `18`).  Python has functions to do that, called `float()` and `int()`.  You can do normal maths (`+-*/`) on floats and ints.

(In case the above isn't clear: `repr` will print strings with quotes around them; it won't print quotes around floats or ints.  `repr` will always print a decimal point for floats, and never for ints).

Note that `float('18.5')` will work, but `float(' 18.5')` won't, because of the stray space.  If you have this problem, look up the `strip()` function which removes leading and trailing spaces from a string.

Comment: +1. Lots of useful hints that should be enough to get the OP 80% of the way done, without doing his work for him. But for the other 20%, you need some explanation of string formatting. For example, `'{} is ${:.2f} per unit'.format('Snickers', .39285714285714285)` Now the OP just needs to figure out where `'Snickers'` and `0.39285714285714285` live in his program.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. It might not come off as very readable if you're not familiar with the techniques used, but it's pretty consistent and easy to understand once you do. Ask in comments if anything is unclear.
Look up [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) for understanding how `products = []` works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import sys

# Gives a list of lists [['Snickers', '33', '84'], ..]
products = [re.sub('[\n \']', '', p).split(',') for p in open("products.txt", "r")]

# Probably not a very good way...
cheapest = ("", sys.float_info.max)

for p in products:
    # Converts price and quantity to float from string, and divide them
    cost = float(p[1]) / float(p[2])

    if cost < cheapest[1]:
        cheapest = (p[0], cost)

    # Snickers is $0.39 per unit
    print "%s is $%.2f per unit." % (p[0], cost)

print "\n%s is the cheapest product and costs $%.2f per unit." % cheapest
```

Produces:

```
Snickers is $0.39 per unit.
Mars is $0.26 per unit.
Bounty is $0.23 per unit.

Bounty is the cheapest product and costs $0.23 per unit.
```